# VBScript - RANDOMIZE (Cbyte(Left(Right(Time(),5),2))) throws 500 for ES locales

Tags: vbscript

Using a standard VBScript Randomize statement (below) which works fine -- most of the time.

**...RANDOMIZE (Cbyte(Left(Right(Time(),5),2)))**

**RANDOMIZE...**

It took a bit, but in digging thru log files, I've noticed that it throws this 500 error:

**Type mismatch: 'Cbyte'**

when the users' languages are non-English.

I tried changing the Session.LCID (I'm using Classic ASP) in a test page but no effect.

Any suggestions for fixing or a work-around?  Thank you...

Comment: If the atrocity `RANDOMIZE (Cbyte(Left(Right(Time(),5),2)))` really is a VBScript standard, then it shouldn't.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a "VBScript standard" in the strict sense.  It is a hack to provide a more "uniformly distributed random number".  See note below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you're trying to randomise based on the seconds-within-the-minute value:

```
12:34:56 AM
      |---|
      56 AM (right(5))
      ||
      56    (left(2))
```

Now I have no idea of the top of my head what `Time()` would return in a Spanish locale, but it may well be something like `12:34:56 de la mañana`.

What I *do* know is that relying on a specific presentation format in a globalised world is a bad idea. In your case, it may involve trying to convert `left(right("12:34:56 de la mañana",5),2)`, or `"añ"`, into a numeric value, something it's not going to be happy with.

If you want a true root cause analysis, I'd suggest catching the conversion error and actually logging what `Time()` is presenting itself as when it errors.

If you just want to *fix* it, find a way to get the seconds that doesn't depend on locale, for example:

```
secs = Second(Time())
```

> As an aside, I'm not sure why you think this is even needed. The documentation for the VBScript Randomise function states that, if an argument is not given, the value returned by the system timer is used as the new seed value. Hence it's already based on the current time.

Comment: The statement:


RANDOMIZE (Cbyte(Left(Right(Time(),5),2)))


seems to be the "go to" one online for creating random values in vbScript.  In case anyone finds this & is looking for a better solution, I propose paxdiablo's version:


RANDOMIZE  (Cbyte(Second(Time())))


This gives a more uniformly distributed random number than just "RANDOMIZE" (i.e. "RANDOMIZE" tends to return certain values more often than others).  And, it also avoids the issue of International User Locales that I seemed to have encountered.

Comment: @Kringle - (1) The `CByte` in `RANDOMIZE (Cbyte(Second(Time())))` is waste. (2) Is there evidence or documention for the claim that plain Randomize gives less "uniformly distributed random number"(s) than a time based seed?

Comment: Re: evidence.  Based upon personal experience of less than uniformly distributed random numbers I researched the issue years ago and found the CByte hack.  It was only recently with adding additional languages to the site that the issue at hand arose. Of course, I can no longer find the reference.  This article hints at problems with Randomize, but I would NOT want to rely upon it as proof: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/406b050e-afea-44dc-8237-b8a29416d4d1/vbscript-truly-random-numberpassword-generators?forum=ITCG

Comment: @Kringle: For what it's worth, following links from your own seem to indicate that the VBS random number generator is a 24-bit LCG with periodicity of the full 16-million-odd values. While that's not ideal as a true random number generator, it should be good enough for most purposes. If it's accurate, then the only other possible problem would be a shortage of starting seeds which would limit the number of unique sequence start points. Given you allow for sixty (one per second-in-a-minute), anything more than that from raw `randomize` would probably be better.